# Best way Selecting comments on multiple posts

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a activity stream just like Google+ or Facebook.

My Problem is im really unsure whats the best way to query comments on multiple posts.

The easiest way is just selecting the comments in a loop, but this is really not the way i want to go.

Another possibility is joining them together.

```
SELECT c. *, p. *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.post_id = c.post_id
WHERE something = something
```

Or selecting them separately.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE something = something

SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1 OR post_id = 2 OR post_id = 3
```

Is there a better way to do that?

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE <condition>
)
```

Or, if you know the `post_id`s:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: The secound one is helpful but not quite the answer to my question.